# HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' plus username and hostname

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've found the variable `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to show the timestamp in `history` output.

I'd like to know if is there some way to show username and hostname as well.

Comment: Citing the bash manual: "Many programs read input from the user a line at a time.  The GNU History library is able to keep track of those lines, associate arbitrary data with each line, and utilize information from previous lines in composing new ones." This and the rest of the manual hints at and tells of the fact that History is attached to a user interactive shell account, on a specific host. If you are a syst-adm, nothing prevents you from scraping all your users' shell account History files, adding user and host in front of each history file line and then consolidating all of it.

Comment: Or, if the "scraping" must be real time and you want to see cmds happening as time goes by on your privileged console, not at regular intervals, you could engineer pushing each new History file line entry for each user on each host to a central repository via `ssh`. This suggests executing logic on each user shell account for each one of their terminal, and opening an ssh tunnel to a central repo, a fairly complicated setup with dubious security implications in my opinion. Why would you want to do this anyway ?